Flutter - Image height in SliverAppBar.large is not full size all the way to the BottomNavigationBar on different phones
The image does not cover the entire screen height all the way to the BottomNavigationBar,
it behaves differently on various screen sizes.(Tested on Iphone 15 and pixel 8)
How can I make the image in SliverAppBar.large cover the entire screen height to the  BottomNavigationBar consistently across all devices?

import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';




void main() {
  runApp(const MainApp());
}

class MainApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainApp({super.key});

  @override
  State<MainApp> createState() => _MainAppState();
}

class _MainAppState extends State<MainApp> {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;

  static const List<Widget> _pages = [
    HomePage(),
    Center(child: Text('Search')),
    Center(child: Text('Notification')),
    Center(child: Text('Settings')),
  ];

  void _onItemTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.purpleAccent,
        body: Center(
          child: _pages.elementAt(_selectedIndex),
        ),
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items: const [
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.home),
              label: 'Home',
            ),`your text`
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.search),
              label: 'Search',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.notifications),
              label: 'Notifications',
            ),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
              label: 'Settings',
            ),
          ],
          currentIndex: _selectedIndex,
          selectedItemColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.primary,
          onTap: _onItemTapped,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomePage({super.key});

  double _getHeight(BuildContext context) {
    final height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    final bottomNavigationHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom;
    final devicePixelRatio = MediaQuery.of(context).devicePixelRatio;
    return height -
        (kBottomNavigationBarHeight * devicePixelRatio) +
        bottomNavigationHeight;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: [
        SliverAppBar.large(
          title: const Center(child: Text('TITLE')),
          expandedHeight: _getHeight(context),
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
            collapseMode: CollapseMode.pin,
            background: Stack(
              fit: StackFit.expand,
              children: [
                CachedNetworkImage(
                    imageUrl:
                        'https://developers.elementor.com/docs/assets/img/elementor-placeholder-image.png',
                    fit: BoxFit.cover),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        SliverList(
          delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
            (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Container(
                margin: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                height: 100.0,
                child: const Card(
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              );
            },
            childCount: 10,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

